# Tracking usage of files

Tags: ubuntu, video

I have a vast video folder, sizing about 700GB.

I am having a lot of trouble determining what files have been accessed and if possible I would like to have an option where I can just play videos that I have never listened to before.

I am on Ubuntu Linux, and I was wondering whether there are tools out there that allows me to track that. I don't want to be tied down to a specific player.

Answer (score 1):

You really would need to use some sort of video player/media library software that can keep track of that information for you.  If your FS is tracking access timestamps, you *might* be able to use those.  However, if your file manager does something like read metadata (like codec, height x width, thumbnail) from a video when you open the folder, then atimes aren't going to be of any use either.

The alternative is to have a "new videos" or "unwatched videos" folder for all your new stuff.  Don't move it to your main collection until you've watched it at least once.

Comment: One way to keep track of new videos would be to hard or symbolic link them in an `unwatched` directory. Once you've finished watching them, remove the link.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally unix systems (including Linux) track the date when a file was last read: its access time, often called atime for short. With these, you can detect that you haven't watched a video because its atime is the same as its mtime (modification time, the time you see in the `ls -l` output). On the command line, `ls -lutr` shows files with their access times. There are ways to locate files in a directory according to various time-related criteria, using `find` or zsh.

Ubuntu nowadays turns off access times, because there's a performance penalty. You can reenable them by editing `/etc/fstab` and changing the line for a filesystem to include the `atime` option, as in

```
/dev/sda1  /  ext4  errors=remount-ro,atime  0  1
```

(You may see `UUID=…` in the first column.) This is a per-filesystem setting, you can't enable atimes only for a directory tree (unless you make it a separate filesystem).

You can also access your files through [loggedfs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/loggedfs) [image: Install loggedfs]. This is a virtual filesystem that shows a view of the “real“ files underneath, and in addition logs all accesses. The [documentation](http://loggedfs.sourceforge.net/) is a little scarce.

Comment: Wouldn't the atimes get updated as soon as, say, a file manager looked at the file to read any metadata about the video or generate a thumbnail?  I'd expect that relying on atimes for this kind of thing would be very unreliable.

Comment: @afrazier: The atime is updated as soon as anything reads the file, so if your file manager pulls in video metadata (duration, codec, etc.) or a preview, the atime is updated (if it's enabled). You can avoid this with loggedfs by watching the videos through it but only browsing the underlying filesystem with a thumbnail-showing file manager. Or maybe loggedfs is able to discriminate between file manager access patterns and player access patterns, I don't know it well enough to tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use **lsof** and **fuser** commands

**lsof** - gives you which files are open

**fuser** - gives processes are using which files

Links:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6066842.html